# How I can set images and custom styles to operator header title If the JSON key matches only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, angular5

```js
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { interval } from 'rxjs/observable/interval';

import { IChartModel } from './model/flow-data';
import { HelperService } from '../../core/helper/helper.service';
import { NgFlowchartService } from './ng-flowchart.service';

declare let $;



@Component({
  selector: 'app-ng-flowchart',
  templateUrl: './ng-flowchart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ng-flowchart.component.css'],
})
export class NgFlowchartComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy {
  @Input('data') flowchartData: IChartModel;
  @Input() event: any;
  

  currentElement = 'dp_flowchart';
  // operatorId = 2;
  operatorId: string;
  // flowchartData;
  possibleZooms = [0.5, 0.75, 1, 2, 3];
  currentZoom = 2;
  subscribeInterval: any;

  constructor(
    private helperService: HelperService,
    private ngFlowchartService: NgFlowchartService
  ) { }

  private autoSaveWorkflow() {
    const $flowchart = $('#' + this.currentElement);
    const source = interval(1000);
    this.subscribeInterval = source.subscribe(val => {
      const flowchartData = $flowchart.flowchart('getData');
      const currentData = JSON.stringify(flowchartData);
      const previousData = localStorage.getItem('ui.flowchart');
      if (previousData !== currentData) {
        localStorage.setItem('ui.flowchart', currentData);
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ngFlowchartService.currentMessage.subscribe(message => {
      if (message.action && message.action === 'ng-clear-editor') {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.clearEditor();
        }, 100);
      }
    });
  }

  setFlowchartData(data) {
    const $flowchart = $('#' + this.currentElement);
    $flowchart.flowchart('setData', data);
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    // console.log(changes);
    this.dataChanges(changes);
  }

  private initFlowchartData() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('ui.flowchart')) {
      return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ui.flowchart'));
    } else {
      return this.flowchartData;
    }
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.advanceOption();
      this.autoSaveWorkflow();
    }, 100);
  }

  private dataChanges(changes) {
    if (changes.hasOwnProperty('event')) {
      if (changes.event.currentValue) {
        if (changes.event.previousValue) {
          /** Have current and previous state */
          const data = {
            curIn: +(changes.event.currentValue.inputCount),
            preIn: +(changes.event.previousValue.inputCount),
            curOut: +(changes.event.currentValue.outputCount),
            preOut: +(changes.event.previousValue.outputCount)
          };

          if (data.curIn !== data.preIn || data.curOut !== data.preOut) {
            this.addEndPoint(changes.event.currentValue);
          }
        } else {
          /** Have only current state */
          const data = {
            curIn: +(changes.event.currentValue.inputCount),
            curOut: +(changes.event.currentValue.outputCount)
          };

          if (data.curIn !== 1 || data.curOut !== 1) {
            this.addEndPoint(changes.event.currentValue);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private addEndPoint(endpoint) {
    // console.log(endpoint);
    /**
     * 1. Find the component in the chart data (using unique identifier - type as 'Event')
     * 2. If already +++++input & output endpoints there then create remaining only
     * 3. If input or output count less the previous one and have a connection (link)
     *    associated with the endpoint then popup comfirmation dialog for removing the
     *    desired in/out.
     */
    const $flowchart = $('#' + this.currentElement);
    const flowchartData = $flowchart.flowchart('getData');

    Object.keys(flowchartData['operators']).forEach((key) => {
      if (endpoint.eventName === flowchartData.operators[key].type.eventName) {
        let inLen = Object.keys(flowchartData.operators[key].properties.inputs).length;
        let outLen = Object.keys(flowchartData.operators[key].properties.outputs).length;
        const _inLen = +endpoint.inputCount - inLen;
        const _outLen = +endpoint.outputCount - outLen;

        let loopFlag = false;
        if (_inLen !== 0) {
          loopFlag = true;
          if (_inLen < 0) {
            inLen = inLen + _inLen;
            for (let i = inLen; i > Math.abs(inLen + _inLen); i--) {
              const _key = Object.keys(flowchartData.operators[key].properties.inputs)[i];
              delete flowchartData.operators[key].properties.inputs[_key];
            }
          } else {
            for (let i = (inLen - 1); i < (inLen + _inLen); i++) {
              flowchartData.operators[key].properties.inputs['input_' + i] = {
                label: 'IN_' + (i + 1)
              };
            }
          }
        }
        if (_outLen !== 0) {
          loopFlag = true;
          if (_outLen < 0) {
            outLen = outLen + _outLen;
            for (let i = outLen; i > Math.abs(outLen + _outLen); i--) {
              const _key = Object.keys(flowchartData.operators[key].properties.outputs)[i];
              delete flowchartData.operators[key].properties.outputs[_key];
            }
          } else {
            for (let i = (outLen - 1); i < (outLen + _outLen); i++) {
              flowchartData.operators[key].properties.outputs['output_' + i] = {
                label: 'OUT_' + (i + 1)
              };
            }
          }
        }

        if (loopFlag) {
          $flowchart.flowchart('setData', flowchartData);
        }

      }
    });
  }

  private advanceOption() {
    const self = this;
    const $flowchart = $('#' + this.currentElement);
    const $container = $flowchart.parent();
    const cx = $flowchart.width() / 2;
    const cy = $flowchart.height() / 2;

    // Panzoom initialization...
    $flowchart.panzoom();
    // Centering panzoom
    $flowchart.panzoom('pan', -cx + $container.width() / 2, -cy + $container.height() / 2);
    // Panzoom zoom handling...
    const possibleZooms = [0.5, 0.75, 1, 2, 3];
    let currentZoom = 2;
    $container.on('mousewheel.focal', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const delta = (e.delta || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta) || e.originalEvent.detail;
      const zoomOut: any = delta ? delta < 0 : e.originalEvent.deltaY > 0;
      currentZoom = Math.max(0, Math.min(possibleZooms.length - 1, (currentZoom + (zoomOut * 2 - 1))));
      $flowchart.flowchart('setPositionRatio', possibleZooms[currentZoom]);
      $flowchart.panzoom('zoom', possibleZooms[currentZoom], {
        animate: false,
        focal: e
      });
    });

    // Apply the plugin on a standard, empty div...
    $flowchart.flowchart({
      data: this.initFlowchartData(),
      onOperatorCreate: function (operatorId, operatorData, fullElement) {
        // console.log(fullElement);
        // console.log('New operator created. Operator ID: "' + operatorId + '", operator title: "' + operatorData.properties.title + '".');
        return true;
      },
      onOperatorSelect: function (operatorId, data) {
        self.componentSelect.emit({
          id: operatorId,
          title: $flowchart.flowchart('getOperatorTitle', operatorId),
          data: $flowchart.flowchart('getOperatorData', operatorId)
        });
        return true;
      },
      // Operators Unselected
      onOperatorUnselect: function () {
        self.componentDeSelected.emit({
          action: 'operator-deselected'
        });
        return true;
      },
      onOperatorDelete: function (operatorId) {
        const operatorType = $flowchart.flowchart('getOperatorData', operatorId).type;
        if (operatorType.eventName) {
          /** Once remove event from editor need to enable it again in event panel */
          self.ngFlowchartService.send({
            action: 'ng-event-deleted',
            data: {
              eventName: operatorType.eventName,
              operatorId: operatorId
            }
          });
        }
        return true;
      },
      onLinkDelete: function (linkId, forced) {
        // delete self.flowchartData['links'][linkId];
        // console.log('Link deleted. Link ID: "' + linkId + '", link color: "' + $flowchart.flowchart('getLinkMainColor', linkId) + '".');
        return true;
      },
      onLinkCreate: function (linkId, linkData) {
        if (self.rule && self.rule.isEnabled) {
          const fromoprtype = $flowchart.flowchart('getOperatorData', linkData.fromOperator).type;
          const tooprtype = $flowchart.flowchart('getOperatorData', linkData.toOperator).type;
          const rule = self.rule.rules['rule'];
          const firstRule = fromoprtype['type'] || 'Component';
          const secondRule = tooprtype['type'] || 'Component';
          return rule[firstRule + ':' + secondRule];
        }

        self.flowchartData['links'][linkId] = linkData;
        delete self.flowchartData['links'][linkId]['internal'];
        // console.log('New link created. Link ID: "' + linkId + '", link color: "' + linkData.color + '".');
        return true;
      },
      onLinkSelect: function (linkId) {
        const flowchartObject = $flowchart.flowchart('getData');
        const linkObject = flowchartObject.links[linkId];
        const fromOperator = flowchartObject.operators[linkObject.fromOperator];
        const toOperator = flowchartObject.operators[linkObject.toOperator];
        const fromType = fromOperator.type.hasOwnProperty('eventName') ? 'Event' : 'Component';
        const toType = toOperator.type.hasOwnProperty('eventName') ? 'Event' : 'Component';
        const title = `Link: ${fromOperator.properties.title} - ${toOperator.properties.title}`;
        self.componentSelect.emit({
          id: linkId,
          title: title,
          data: {
            type: {
              isLink: true,
              data: linkObject,
              linkData: {
                fromOperator: fromOperator.properties.title,
                fromType: fromType,
                toOperator: toOperator.properties.title,
                toType: toType
              }
            }
          }
        });

        return true;
      }
    });

    const $draggableOperators = $('.draggable_operator');

    $draggableOperators.draggable({
      cursor: 'move',
      opacity: 0.7,
      // helper: 'clone',
      appendTo: 'body',
      zIndex: 1000,
      
    });
  }

  private addNewComponent(event: any) {
    // console.log(event);
    const $flowchart = $('#' + this.currentElement);
    let componentTitle;
    componentTitle = (event.dragData.eventName) ? `${event.dragData.displayName}` : `${event.dragData.name}`;
    this.operatorId = this.helperService.getUniqueId();
    if (event.dragData.eventName) {
      /** Component is an 'event' type */
      const flowchartObject = $flowchart.flowchart('getData');
      const operators = flowchartObject.operators;
      for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(operators).length; i++) {
        const component = operators[Object.keys(operators)[i]];
        if (event.dragData.eventName === component.type.eventName) {
          return;
        }
      }

      /** 1. Send operator details back to event panel for disabling the dropped event
       *  2. Once remove event from editor need to enable it again in event panel
       *  2. After rerender pipeline we need to set it again (pending)
       */
      this.ngFlowchartService.send({
        action: 'ng-event-added',
        data: {
          eventName: event.dragData.eventName,
          operatorId: this.operatorId
        }
      });
    }

    const inputObject = {};
    const outputObject = {};
    if (event.dragData.hasOwnProperty('componentUIMetaData') && event.dragData.componentUIMetaData.hasOwnProperty('connector')) {
      const iCount = event.dragData.componentUIMetaData.connector.endpoint.in || 0;
      const oCount = event.dragData.componentUIMetaData.connector.endpoint.out || 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < iCount; i++) {
        inputObject['input_' + i] = {
          label: 'IN_' + (i + 1)
        };
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < oCount; i++) {
        outputObject['output_' + i] = {
          label: 'OUT_' + (i + 1)
        };
      }
    }

    const operatorData = {
      top: event.nativeEvent.offsetY - 20,
      left: event.nativeEvent.offsetX - 20,
      type: event.dragData,
      properties: {
        title: componentTitle,
        inputs: inputObject,
        outputs: outputObject,
      }
    };

    // this.operatorId++;
    $flowchart.flowchart('createOperator', this.operatorId, operatorData);

    if (event.dragData.hasOwnProperty('type') && (event.dragData.type === 'Event')) {
      const cssClass = 'flowchart-operator-title ui-draggable-handle titleClass';
      event.nativeEvent.currentTarget.childNodes[1].lastChild.children[0].classList.value = cssClass;
    }
  }

  onComponentDrop(event: any) {
    // console.log(event);
    this.addNewComponent(event);
  }

  deleteSelected() {
    const $flowchart = $('#' + this.currentElement);
    $flowchart.flowchart('deleteSelected');
  }

  getFlowchartData() {
    const $flowchart = $('#' + this.currentElement);
    return $flowchart.flowchart('getData');
  }

 
  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.subscribeInterval) {
      this.subscribeInterval.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="flowchart-example">
  <div id="chart_container">
    <div class="zoom-panel-container">
    
     
    </div>
    <div class="flowchart-example-container" id="dp_flowchart" droppable [dropScope]="'component'" (onDrop)="onComponentDrop($event)"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

https://github.com/sdrdis/jquery.flowchart  enter link description here
I am trying to add custom styles on operator header title to change the color it using jquery/JS but the issue is styles is coming to every operator while dragging.
I have to add custom styles on this class: "flowchart-operator-title ui-draggable-handle"
My requirement:
Add Custom styles if the JSON key matches only as well as  add images only if condition matches. Can you please help?
Here inside code i am using function addNewComponent which i am used for drag and drop

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: please share relevant html and jquery/javascript you have tried so far